# Is this the way the dynamic programming version of maximum subarray sum algorithm works?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, sub-array

At the `dynamic programming` chapter in my algorithms textbook I have an example of how to solve the [maximum sub array sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) using this technique. I am not sure if I got the idea behind the algorithm so I will describe here how I think it works (after reading several times about it and doing several examples).

Basically, you have an array `A` of size `n`, and you want to find the maximum sub array sum of that array. The sub array with maximum sum can be somewhere in the right half of the array, left half, or somewhere in the middle. So you recursively call the function to compute the maximum sub array sum from the left and, then, from the right side of the array. Then, you compute the maximum sub array sum that from the middle of the array to the end, then compute the maximum sub array sum from the middle to the beginning of the array (it's length is not necessarily `n/2`). Then, if the sum of maximum sub array sum form left plus maximum sub array sum from the right is bigger than the maximum sub array sum from the left half (the one computed recursively ) and the maximum sub array sum from the right half (also computed recursively), then the maximum sub array sum is in the one in middle. Otherwise is the maximum of the one from left half and the one from right half (those were computed recursively).

Did I got the working mechanism of the algorithm?

This is the function that I was analyzing:

```
int maxSubArraySum(int* arr, int n)
{
    if(n == 1)
    {
        return arr[0];
    }
    int m = n / 2;
    int left = maxSubArraySum(arr, m);
    int right = maxSubArraySum(arr + m, n - m);
    int leftsum = INT_MIN, rightsum = INT_MIN, sum = 0;

    for(int i = m; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        rightsum = std::max(rightsum, sum);
    }

    sum = 0;

    for(int i = (m - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        leftsum = std::max(leftsum, sum);
    }

    int retval = std::max(left, right);
    return std::max(retval, leftsum + rightsum);    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's nothing at all like the maximum subarray algorithm. Seriously, no resemblance whatsoever.

Comment: @user2357112 You mean only my description or also the function?

Comment: Actually, was this supposed to be an example of how to use dynamic programming, or an example of a suboptimal algorithm that dynamic programming can improve on? Because while it doesn't bear any resemblance to Kadane's algorithm (the dynamic programming solution), it is still a working algorithm to solve the problem. It's just not dynamic programming and not as fast as dynamic programming.

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be an example of how to solve this problem using a dynamic programming approach. It is pretty sad to hear that I got a wrong example in my book. But does my description match the code?

Comment: Well, you've successfully described the algorithm you were presented with. If this description is supposed to be read by other people, rather than just to help you understand the algorithm, some parts should probably be made less ambiguous, but the description is accurate as it stands.

Comment: While this algorithm doesn't have as much subproblem reuse as I'd usually expect out of something described as dynamic, I suppose it could be viewed that way. It definitely doesn't redo subproblems, and in retrospect, while Kadane's algorithm is substantially faster, I'm not sure it really reuses subproblem results *more*.

Answer (score 0):

One does not need always Recursion to achieve dynamic programming. The Kadane's  algorithm is a simple example of dynamic programming by breaking down the problem into subproblems reused n-1 times (compare the last so far maximum sub array to the current one n-1 times).